# problem with Remote-desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to connect to my rdp but when i want to logon in my remote desktop , after puting user and pass i get this error :

```
the terminal server has exceeded the maximum number of allowed connections
```

my server : windows 2003 . 
 what am i going to do ? 
please help me .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're running in the default mode where it only allows two simultaneous connections. There are already two idle sessions connected, so you probably just need to fire up Terminal Server manager and kill one (or more) of the idle sessions. You'll be able to connect after doing this.

Comment: how can i kill one of the sessions ? 
thanks

Comment: From the horse's mouth: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759296(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Connect to the server's console via RDP then fire up Terminal Services Manager to kill off one of the two in-use sessions (which are probably idle due to someone forgetting to log off).

```
mstsc /admin /v:serverName
```

Comment: yikes. My answer is startling similar to ErikA's. Honest, I was slowly typing while watching a horrible webinar, not plagiarizing!

Comment: Happens all the time. Don't worry about it.

Comment: No problem at all.